# FM demodulation circuit

Tags: ltspice, frequency-modulation, demodulation

I'm doing an FM demodulator circuit. I am copying the circuit from LTspice in the first image) to Multsim (the second image.)

Is what I did in Multisim correct? How can I get a graph from Multisim like one in the first picture?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not stick with ltspice? its free and easy to use...

Comment: Because it's required for us to use Multisim

Answer (score 1):

> *Is what I did in Multisim correct?*

Did you forget to connect this node (you did connect it in LTSpice): -

[image]

Comment: And the RST/R2 node is not connected to the supply as well

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might differ is the model of the 555 timer, so make sure that is equivalent between the two softwares.

Here is how to plot nodes in multisim (plot the same nodes)
https://www2.mvcc.edu/users/faculty/jfiore/Circuits2/RLSim_Basics.pdf